# Close JavaScript PopUp Window that resides under another window

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript PopUp window with an option for search. While I search the result is populated, but that is coming in a second PopUp Window[that is on the top of the first Window]. So currently two PopUp windows are populating in the manner of one over the another, but I want only the PopUp window having result. So how can I close only the PopUp window that exists in the background[I tried window.close(), but it will close all the PopUp's].

Thanks,
Dias Jacob

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a popup to a variable you can access that variable again to close the window:

```
// opens popup
var myFirstPopup = window.open('http://wwe.example.com');

// closes popup again
myFirstPopup.clopse();
```

This way if you name both of your popup you can close one one while keeping the other one open.